# Does probability of $1$% means that it is guaranteed to get a success event if I do $100$ tries?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let us suppose I have $100$ balls in a container, each one has a different number ( from $1$ to $100$).

I want to pick a ball, and we'll suppose this is a random process ( i.e. choosing the ball is random).

## Question $1$

Given that the whole universe of balls ( a.k.a the set `Ω`) is made up of only those $100$ balls in the container, I can say that probability of picking up the ball `i` is 1% (`i` is any number from $1$ to $100$)?

## Question $2$

If the answer to question $1$ is "yes", and if I repeat the picking of a ball $100$ times (each time I put it back in the container, and I will suppose that the next pickup is unrelated to the previous one, hence randomness), Is it guaranteed that the ball `i` will appear at least one time during the $100$ pickups?

**Note:** I am not a total beginner in maths, but I am confused about something: does a n% chance means that it is guaranteed to get n successes out of $100$ tries, or it is not guaranteed unless I repeat the tries till infinity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reduce the number of outcomes from 100 to 2 and you have this question: If you flip a fair coin twice, are you guaranteed to get one head and one tail?  This one you can verify experimentally as well as analytically.

Like Ted says in the comments, there are no certainties in probability.  There's also no such thing as "infinitely many trials."
The best we can do is say something like the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers):

If you draw one ball from the 100 $n$ times, and keep a running total of the fraction of the times that ball $i$ is drawn, this fraction converges in probability to $0.01$ as $n$ becomes arbitrarily large.

Comment: thanks for the ultra fast response :)
well no of course it is not guaranteed to get one head and one tail in the example you mentioned, but this being said, what is the verbal translation of " n% chance of getting an event to occur " ? according to your answer it is absolutely not " you are guaranteed to get n successes per cent tries i.e. per one hundred tries".

this is confusing my understanding of probability a lot

Comment: @HaidarMehsen: A probability of $1\%$ means  that, on average, if you do $100$ trials, then you should get $1$ success. This is an average—not a guarantee of what will happen. It is entirely possible that you get $100$ failures: assuming the trials are independent, this occurs $0.99^{100}=36.6\ldots\%$ of the time. Think of the number $1\%$ as an indication of how *confident* you are something will happen in a given trial, not a fortune ball that will guarantee that you will get a success after a given number of trials.

Comment: There are *never* guarantees. If you flip a coin 1000 times and get heads every time, there's still no "guarantee" that it'll be tails the 1001st time.

Comment: @Joe so the only way it is guaranteed to get 1 success out of 100 tries, and given that what I mean by 1 success out of 100 tries is that if i gather the set (not mathematical set, it can have repeated elements) of all the outcomes then the only way I can group the outcomes into 99 fails and 1 successes is that I make infinite number of tries?

Comment: There is *never* a guarantee unless the outcome is the only possible one. Get over this notion.

Comment: @HaidarMehsen Kind of. With an infinite number of trials, no successes is a possible outcome, but it has probability 0. Infinity can be weird like that.

Comment: The actual odds of choosing a specific ball in a run of 100 tries is 1-(0.99^100) or about 63.4%. For a run of 250 tries it is 91.9%. As the number of tries increases it approaches but never reaches 100%.

Answer (score 3):

An $n$% chance means that, if you try a very large number of times, the fraction of successes will be approximately $n/100$. Additionally, as you do more and more tries, the difference between the measured fraction and $n/100$ will tend to get smaller and smaller.

However, while the probability of getting zero successes gets smaller and smaller as the number of tries $N$ goes up, it is never zero. That probability is given by the simple formula
$$
P(\mathrm{no\;success}) = \left(1 - \frac{n}{100}\right)^N
$$

And finally, an important point. This probability applies to a set of $N$ trials taken as a whole. The probability of success for any individual trial is still $n/100$, no matter how many successes or failures occurred before it. If you draw from the container 10000 times and never draw ball 15, then you've been astonishingly unlucky, but on the next draw, ball 15 still has a 1% chance of being chosen.

Answer (score 1):

As a student and teacher of maths, I'm going to approach this pretty informally.

Measuring probability, in the case of finite sample spaces, is a ratio of favorable outcomes to total outcomes. So, if you have 100 balls numbered 1 to 100, the probability of selecting ball 1 is, well, 1 in 100. There is one outcome you desire of the hundred available.

This does not mean, however, that if you draw 100 balls with replacement, you are gauranteed to select ball 1 once. You could possibly never draw it!